# Error in bin/sh when installing automake-1.13

Tags: compiling, make, automake

I'm attempting to install automake-1.13.4 on my system.

First, I do `./configure` which creates a Makefile compatible with my system.

However, when I execute `make`, it runs for a bit, but then returns the following error message:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token ||
/bin/sh: -c: line 5: `    {  || exec 5>&2 >$tmp 2>&1; } \'
make: *** [doc/amhello-1.0.tar.gz] Error 1
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is occuring.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your system? does it have an existing version of automake - or are you trying a bootstrap install?

Comment: The system I'm using runs Red Hat Linux. And yes, I currently have automake 1.11.1 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. This error is related to the `amhello-1.0.tar.gz` file.

The originally provided file was not configured properly for my system. Therefore, if I rebuild the file myself, and replace the original `amhello-1.0.tar.gz`, then I can run `make` with no errors.

To see how to rebuild `amhello-1.0.tar.gz` so that its configured properly to your system, see the link below:

https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Creating-amhello.html

By the way, it is also important to run `autoreconf -vfi` before compiling the package.

Answer (score 1):

```
{  ||
```

A command is missing between `{` and `||`. But that may not be the only problem.